# why is add-hook in use-package not erroring for function that does not exist

Tags: init-file, use-package, js2-mode

I have added a `(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook 'my-js2-mode-setup)` the following hook to a use-package `init` section:

```
(use-package js2-mode
  :ensure t
  :interpreter (("node" . js2-mode))
  :mode "\\.\\(js\\|json\\)$"
  :bind (:map js2-mode-map
              ("C-c C-p" . js2-print-json-path))
  :init
  (add-hook 'js2-mode-hook 'my-js2-mode-setup)
  (add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'js2-minor-mode)
  (setq js2-highlight-level 3
        js2-mode-show-parse-errors nil
        js2-mode-show-strict-warnings nil))
```

I was not convinced the hook was running so I removed the `my-js2-mode-set-up` function and no error has occurred.

Why is this?  Should I have the `init` section enclosed in a `progn` as there is more than one statement?

Comment: You don't need to `progn` if there is more than one statement. I replaced `my-js2-mode-setup` with a function defined in `:preface` and it works just fine.

Comment: what is preface?

Comment: It is evaluated before everything else. Usually used for defining functions. Like this `(use-package js2-mode :preface (defun foo() (message "foo here")) ...`

Comment: thanks, where would you use defadvice?

Comment: How is defadvice relevant to this question?

Comment: apologies, it is not, I'm just not sure about how use-package is working with hooks and defadvice and others

Comment: To see what `use-package` does under the hood, select the whole `(use-package ...)` and call `emacs-lisp-macroexpand`

Answer (score 1):

Use-package is designed NOT to stop on error. All errors are reported in the `*Warnings*` buffer. This way you can almost always start your emacs and fix any errors from within Emacs.

From use-package README https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package:

> Additionally, if an error occurs while initializing or configuring a package, 
>   this will not stop your Emacs from loading. Rather, the error will be captured 
>   by use-package, and reported to a special `*Warnings*` popup buffer, so that you 
>   can debug the situation in an otherwise functional Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

The `add-hook` forms need to go in the `:config` block instead of `:init`.

As the package is not yet *require*d at the time of evaluating `:init`, the *HOOK* to which the `add-hook` is adding a function is not yet defined. Even so, trying to do `add-hook` will "work" as that new *HOOK* will be initialized with a *nil* value (From `C-h f add-hook`). **BUT** that also means that that *HOOK* will not get the initial value, if non-nil, as set in the package, as the package is not yet loaded.

Here's a little dummy example:

Let's say there is a `foo.el`:

```el
;; my foo package -- foo.el
(defvar foo-hook (lambda () (message "hi")))
(provide 'foo)
```

.. and the user's `init.el`

```el
;; my init.el
(use-package foo
  :init
  (add-hook 'foo-hook #'ignore))
```

So I would suggest to always do `add-hook` calls in `:config`. That way:

- First the package gets loaded
- Then that *HOOK* gets an initial value as set by the package (though, it is very rare for a hook to have a non-nil initial value)
- Then the `add-hook` from the `:config` gets triggered.

Comment: `add-hook` works even if the package is not loaded yet. From the docstring: "If HOOK is void, it is first set to nil."

Comment: @compunaut Thanks! You are correct. I now remember that certain packages do not care to formally define hooks with `defvar` or `defcustom` (which is bad) and initialize those with just `add-hook`. I still stand by the suggestion of adding hooks in `:config` for better config robustness.